# Can I use Ethernet transceivers on InfiniBand devices?

Tags: infiniband, optical-media

Specifically, can I use 40GBASE-whatever transceivers as 40G QDR transceiver on common Mellanox devices?

If not, what's the cause of such incompatibility?